# using display flex causes purple border to appear

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following simple HTML structure:

```
<section id="teasers">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="">
                <div class="redbox">
                    <h2 class="two-lines uppercaseme lowercaseme">Behind the Scenes<br/>
                        <span class="lowercaseme">A look at studio life</span>
                    </h2> 
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
               </div>
           </a>
       </div>
</section>
```

And the following CSS applied:

```
.redbox {
    padding: 0 55px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#teasers h2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 7% 0;
}
```

The bug can be seem **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/flex-border-bug/flex-error.html)**. If you reduce the screen size to below 992px.

Basically, applying flex causes the `H2` tag inside `.redbox` to have a purple border. If you remove `display: flex` in the dev tools the purple border vanishes. How come?

Is this a known issue and what is the solution to this?

Comment: The CSS you provided is inside a media query with max-width of 992px. Is  this intended?

Comment: Its `text-decoration` form `a` but i am not sure why its showing on `display: flex` and not on `display: table` or `display: inline-block` for example.

Comment: @Voreny yes thats intended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underline is indeed the `text-decoration` from your block-level link (the wrapping `a`), and it should be there.

It's about floats, not flex. Floats are hiding your underline. And since floats are ignored with flex, the underline reappears. If you remove `float: left` from your `H2` on a screen larger than 992px (container is `block`, not `flex` there), you'll see that underline again.

The question is why the underline *disappears* when floated? It must be related to elements being taken out of the normal flow (much like with absolute positioning): https://jsfiddle.net/b5jagc1m/

Comment: It disappears when floated because the parent collapses since the floated child is not cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the flex piece as to why it shows but as it is a link if you text-`decoration : none`;
this will take off the underline.

Answer (score 2):

You're bumping up against the User Agent Stylesheet.

Since you've wrapped the `h2` in an anchor element, the whole thing is a link. As you may know, visited links by default turn purple.

If you want the underline to be a different color, make an adjustment to your visited links rule:

```
a:visited { color: red; }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4apL0meg/)

Otherwise, simply remove the underline:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4apL0meg/1/)

---

*But why does the underline disappear when `display: flex` is removed?*

Because a child of the flex container is floated. This means that when the container is on, the float is ignored. Per the rules of CSS, flexbox ignores floats on children:

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> - `float` and `clear` have no effect on a flex item, and do not take it out-of-flow.

But when the flex container is deactivated, a [inline formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) resumes, and the `a` element collapses because the floated child is not cleared. ([The `clearfix` div in your code is invalid and doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/3597276)) This takes the underlines with it, but not the text as it exists within block elements.

---

References:

- [Chrome Default Stylesheet](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)
- [Firefox Default Stylesheet](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css)
- [W3C Default Stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)